# Parsing entire ArcSDE database searching for field for export?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, enterprise-geodatabase, export

I'm wanting to parse through an entire ArcSDE database (feature dataset, features classes, tables, everything...) searching for a field (compkey) and export the numbers to a txt file.

Comment: So what's your question exactly? And what DBMS is being used?

Answer (score 3):

If your data is not versioned (or you've compressed and updated the base tables), 
you could just use SQL to query out the IDs.

For a manual, one-time-only, type of query, I've used this SQL query (ORACLE) to generate a second SQL query. You could replace the `COUNT(*) as ROWCOUNT` with a `COMPKEY` and add additional where clause conditions (you will probably want to change `OWNER ='SDE'` to `OWNER IN ('SCHEMA1','SCHEMA2','SCHEMA3')` if you have GIS data in multiple schemas).

```
select 
    'SELECT COUNT(*) as ROWCOUNT,'''|| t.owner||'.'||t.TABLE_NAME||''' as ClassName FROM '||t.OWNER||'.'||t.TABLE_NAME||' UNION' as SelectStatement 
from sde.table_registry t
where t.owner = 'SDE'
and t.owner||'.'||t.TABLE_NAME in (select OWNER||'.'||TABLE_NAME  
from all_tab_cols where column_name = 'COMPKEY' and OWNER ='SDE'
order by t.table_name
```

So the above query will generate a list of select statements with a 'UNION' at the end.

copy/paste that into a new query window (**delete the 'UNION' from the last line)**.  and that will give you your list.  If you are using SQL Developer or Toad, those applications have built-in capability to export to text file.

If your data is versioned, you should probably look at building multi-versioned views for the versioned featureclasses. Assuming that you would be querying from each featureclass/table at the same version, you could do the same sort of union query but using the multi-version views.